# How to use function of another saved file in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a single spreadsheet and while working with app scripts I have created 2 files, **Code.gs** with `onEdit` function and **Data.gs** with `onOpen` function.

with `onOpen` I will take rows and columns and convert them to json data then I want to use that data in **Code.gs**

How do I add up this functionality of taking data from another file?

I really felt the Google unworthy first time because of this

Comment: I'm not sure that I know how to say this but I would say that all of the functions in a project are in the same name space.  You could have put the all of your functions in Code.gs.  Multiple files are available just to make it possible to organize them better but they all share access to the same data.  So you can store the JSON data in say the Script Properties Service and retrieve that data from any function in any file within a project.  And of course all of the functions in a project contained in a  spreadsheet have access to all of the sheets in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I think it might be valuable for your to read the entire section in the Guides section of the documentation called Exploring the Development Environment.

Comment: Typically onEdit(e) and onOpe() are functions that are executed via triggers and so normally you wouldn't call them from other functions and they don't return any values because they're executed by a trigger.

Comment: You can make a new sheet in active spreadsheet, save your json in its cell(s) and to check this sheet/cell(s) from `onEdit()` function.

Comment: That's a good idea @YuriKhristich. I will be compromising with that finally 

Answer (score 1):

Here's four functions that I use to store global data on one of the sheets in a spreadsheet that I just reserve as a hash table.

```
function getGlobals(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var g={};
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    g[vA[i][0]]=vA[i][1];
  }
  return g;
}
    
function setGlobals(dfltObj){
  if(dfltObj){
    const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Globals');
    sh.clearContents();
    let vA=[];
    for(let key in dfltObj) {
      vA.push([key,dfltObj[key]]);
    }
    sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,2).setValues(vA);          
  }
}
  
function getGlobal(name){
  return getGlobals()[name];
}

function setGlobal(name,value){
  var curObj=getGlobals();
  curObj[name]=value; 
  setGlobals(curObj);
}
```

And I could use them in the same file but I prefer to keep all of the files that access the global hash all together in the same file.  Here's how I might use them.

```
function getSheetData(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getGlobal('ssid'));
  const sr = obj.startRow;
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(obj.name);
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  return vs;
}
```

and I could use that function from anywhere in the project by calling it like this:

```
function getSheet2Data() {
  const sh2Data = getSheetData({startRow:2,name:'Sheet2'});
  //and then use the data in the rest of the function.
}
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hey @Cooper thanks for your effort to help, but I don't think that fulfills my need. Maybe I am not completely understanding your code but as far I understood that we can call any function from any file just usually, thanks for that. But I just needed to pass values between triggers as you mentioned in comments. I also looked up on google and there is no way I found we can pass parameters/values between two trigger functions.

Comment: My main focus is to avoid latency, because if I use `onEdit` then it will call my `getGlobals` function will run on every edit which is why I thought if I can first getGlobals when sheet loads  and keep them saved so when any edit is made then it can use those values